# Jquery .load function not posting 4th parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the below jQuery script which posts four variables to a PHP page, a string, HOST IP address, Forwarding IP Address and Current URL. However for some reason the receiving PHP file only gets three variables. The last or the last but one variable is not being received by the PHP Code.

```js
var loadinggif = '../img/loading.gif';

$(document).ready(function() {
  // set up the click event
  $('.btnbg').live('click', function() {
    var toLoad = '../VerifyCode.php';
    $('.content').slideUp('slow', loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#waiting').append('<div id="load"><img src="' + loadinggif + '" alt="Loading" /></div>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');

    function loadContent() {
      var code = $('#code').val();
      var remote_addr = $('#remote_addr').val();
      var forwarded_for = $('#forwarded_for').val();
      var url = $('#url').val();

      $('.content').load(toLoad, {
        'string': code,
        'ipAddr1': remote_addr,
        'ipAddr2': forwarded_for,
        'url': url
      }, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == 'error') {
          var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
          $(".content").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
      }).slideDown('slow', hideLoader());
    }

    function hideLoader() {
      $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Is there any restriction on the `load()` function which I need to consider? The script receives the value from a form and I verified that the values to the script are being received correctly but its the script which is unable to post all four variables to the Verifycode.php page.

## *UPDATE:*

I was trying something and if I put the POST parameters in a separate variable it is working fine. Any explanation on why that would be the case?

```
 var _post = {'string': code,'ipAddr1':remote_addr,'ipAddr2':forwarded_for, 'url':url};

 $('.content').load(toLoad, _post , function(response, status, xhr) {
```

Comment: Please provide: Image of Network tab where we can see sent parameters; PHP code that reads `url` parameter from POST

Comment: I was trying something and if I put the POST parameters in a separate variable it is working fine. Please see my OP for that. Any explanation on why that would be the case?

Comment: @FBP that seems fairly unlikely. Did you change anything else at the same time?

Comment: @ADyson other than the change I mentioned I haven't changed anything.